# Delete operation failed. (Fsys error=32, server error=1015)

Tags: php, ftp

I have a really weird issue with `PHP`, a webserver, and a media server. I have a site on a webserver that uploads an audio file to a mediaserver. The site also takes care of deleting the audio file as well. However, I'm getting a really weird error that I have Googled my brains out trying to find with no luck.

> Warning: ftp_delete() [function.ftp-delete]: Delete operation failed. (Fsys error=32, server error=1015) in /......./page.php on line 175

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After playing around with it some more we were able to figure out that the issue was with the media server. The delete command was coming from the web server, but if the audio file had been played very recently, the media server was keeping the audio file open for streaming and therefore any commands could not be performed on the file itself until the media server released the file. So all we had to do was wait 2 or 3 seconds and we no longer had that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar thing. This is what I did, and the issue was solved

Code:

```
ftp_chmod( $ftpConnection, 777, $filelist ) ;
ftp_get( $ftpConnection, $dest . '\\' . $str, $str, FTP_BINARY ) ;
ftp_delete( $ftpConnection, $str ) ;
```

Comment: After playing around with it some more we were able to figure out that the issue was with the media server. The delete command was coming from the web server, but if the audio file had been played very recently, the media server was keeping the audio file open for streaming and therefore any commands could not be performed on the file itself until the media server released the file. So all we had to do was wait 2 or 3 seconds and we no longer had that problem. Guess I should have updated this when we found that out.